# Update the UI Rotation According to camera rotation

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, raycasting

I have a camera which is showing the userInterface (canvas) object into the front of my camera. **I am only updating my userinterface position if the camera raycast is not hitting my userInterface object collider**. something like this

```
public class UIPlacerAtCamFront : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject userInterface;
    public float placementDistance;
    Vector3 uiPlacementPosition;
    RaycastHit  objectHit; 

    void Update () {

        Vector3 fwd = this.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        //Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, fwd * 50, Color.green);

        if (Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, fwd, out objectHit, 50))
        {
            //raycast hitting the userInterface collider, so do nothing, userinterface is infornt of the camrea already
        }
        else
        {
            //raycast is not hitting userInterfae collider, so update UserInterface position accoding to the camera
            uiPlacementPosition = this.transform.position + this.transform.forward * placementDistance;
            userInterface.transform.position = uiPlacementPosition;
        }

        //Continuously update userInterface rotation according to camera
        userInterface.transform.rotation = this.transform.rotation; 
    }
}
```

The above script has attached with my camera, it displaying the object correctly but as i start to rotate my camera my UI object rotation looks very strange as below image suggested
[image: This is inital correct rotation]

As i rotate, this problem occurs
[image]

I know that the problem is in rotation, so I tired to change my this rotation code

```
    userInterface.transform.rotation = this.transform.rotation;
```

to this

```
userInterface.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (this.transform.localEulerAngles.x,
            0,
            this.transform.localEulerAngles.z);
```

but it bring another strange rotation for me, like given below
[image]

I want that my userinteface object face my camera correclty, even my camera watching the start or end of my userinteface object. How can i rotate my UI according to camera rotation correctly?

Comment: Why are you using a worldspace canvas to immitate a screenspace canvas? Just set the canvas to be screenspace.

Comment: @Draco18s yes you are right but i am making some selection on canvas with camera pointer that why i can't set canvas to screen space. The camera pointer will rotate according to camera and it will make selection from world space UI.

Comment: Why not just make it a child object of the camera, it'll turn and move with the camera without additional scripting.

Comment: @JohnHamilton refer to my previous comment "yes you are right but i am making some selection on canvas with camera pointer that why i can't set canvas to screen space. The camera pointer will rotate according to camera and it will make selection from world space UI. "

Comment: @JohnHamilton if i make it child then it will roate with the parent movement and i will unable to select userinteface object from my camera pointer object

Comment: I'm not saying use screen-space. Make it world-space so it's an actual object, just make it a child of the camera. It will still act like any other object in the level.

Comment: if i make it child then it will roate with the parent movement and i will unable to select userinteface object from my camera pointer object